# Convert XML where output element name is dynamic?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that I need to convert to a more simplified format.  I am sure this can be done with XSLT, but I am unsure how.

I need to convert:

```
<Fields>
  <Field>
    <Name>Element1</Name>
    <Value>Value 1</Value>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>Element2</Name>
    <Value>Value 2</Value>
  </Field>
</Fields>
```

into

```
<Fields>
  <Element1>Value 1</Element1>
  <Element2>Value 2</Element2>
</Fields>
```

This is what I have currently:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Fields/Field/*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your input XML,**

```
<Fields>
  <Field>
    <Name>Element1</Name>
    <Value>Value 1</Value>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>Element2</Name>
    <Value>Value 2</Value>
  </Field>
</Fields>
```

**transformed by this XSLT,**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Fields">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="{Name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**yields this output XML,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fields>
  <Element1>Value 1</Element1>
  <Element2>Value 2</Element2>
</Fields>
```

**as requested.**

Comment: *Important* notice: There are rules for valid xml element names. (1) Names must not begin with a digit. (2) Names cannot start with special characters such as a hyphen or period. (3) Names cannot contain special characters other than the period, hyphen, underscore, and colon.

Comment: You can prevent invalid names to an extent with the double translate method- `<xsl:element name="{translate(Name, translate(Name, $validChars, ''), '')}"/>`, where `$validChars` is a variable containing all characters you want to allow in a name. This is a bit crude though.